# I'm using Magento and I need a solution to implement custom tax rate

Tags: tax-class, shipping-tax

**I have the following tax setting now**

- Subtotal: $10.00
- Shipping & Handling: $5.00
- Tax (at the moment just using 10% of Subtotal) (10%):$1.00
- Grand Total: $16.00

**And I want it like :**

- Subtotal: $10.00
- Shipping & Handling: $5.00
- Tax (need it to be 10% of subtotal [which is working] 
   AND 10% of 54% of shipping & Handling) (10%): $1.27 [$1 as 10% of subtotal and $0.27 for $2.70(which is 54% of $5.00 shipping cost) ]
- Grand Total: $16.27

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 5% is the same as 10% of 50% so just set a tax rate of 5% for shipping.

You can set the tax class for shipping under System -> Configuration -> Tax -> Tax Class -> Tax Class for Shipping

Comment: the above mentioned data is sample for better understanding. - Shipping charges will be different every time.

and I have already set the class "shipping" and it is working as well. But I need percentage of tax on percentage of shipping charges.

Comment: @Vijay you mean the tax rate (%) for shipping will be different every time? Or the actual shipping amount? If the tax rate varies, does it vary on country/state etc, or some other variable?

Comment: thanks for the idea. I was not checking it mathematically. I need to apply tax on 54% of shipping amount. I have updated the question as well. yes doing mathematically percentage and apply to shipping tax class may work.

Comment: and tax rate varies for just couple of states, which I am managing from tax rules. and tax percentage may varies from few orders, so I have to think for customization on tax code as well. Do you have any idea how I can achieve the same with tax module customization?

Comment: 10% of 54% of the shipping cost is just 5.4% of the shipping cost, so this can be handled easily. Using a combination of the standard Magento tax customisations you should be able to achieve what you want: create the shipping tax class, assign it as the tax class for shipping, set the tax rates per country/state/zip and then set the tax rules. I don't see that it needs any customisation.

Comment: I'm bored of saying this: 10% of 54% is 5.4%. So just use the whole shipping amount and set the tax rate to 5.4%. Per your example:

$4.50 * 0.054 = $0.243

(Edit: I see you deleted your comment.)

Comment: yes perfect. thank you. accepting your answer.. but I just get an update about requirement that we need to get actual USPS rates which will be different and then have to subtract our additional handling charges from total shipping and have to add tax on handling amount only. so I need customization for that

like $4.50 total shipping and handling charges
- and $2.5 is actual USPS shipping charges (which is not taxable)
- and $2 is our handling charges(which needs to be taxable)

so for this I must have to do customization. If you can share anything with that would be great help.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure about the additional handling charges. I'd look into extensions that provide handling fees and find one that allows the fee to have its own tax class. You really don't want to start modifying the Magento tax routines.

Comment: thank you. I am using shipstation and checking the same as well. Will try not to change default tax routine.